# Adding dependencies to stack project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am very new to Haskell and I am trying to add the graphics package gloss to my stack project but I am encountering problems when doing `stack build`.

I have created my stack project as follows:

```
LICENSE         package.yaml        stack.yaml
README.md       package.yaml~       stack.yaml.lock
Setup.hs        project39.cabal     stack.yaml~
TAGS            project39.cabal~    test
```

and edited the `stack.yaml`and the cabal file as follows:

```
# extra-deps:
# - acme-missiles-0.3
# - git: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack.git
#   commit: e7b331f14bcffb8367cd58fbfc8b40ec7642100a
# - gloss-1.13.2.1
```

```
executable project39-exe
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_project39
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , project39
    , gloss
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

In the `src` file Lib.hs I have added a `Import Graphics.Gloss` to test if it works:

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where
import Graphics.Gloss
```

but when I then do `stack build` I get the following error:

```
    Could not load module ‘Graphics.Gloss’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘gloss-1.13.2.1’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘gloss’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Graphics.Gloss
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am unsure what the problem here is and how to solve it.

Comment: You say "`src` file `Lib.hs`", but `Lib` doesn't appear in the cabal file snippet you showed us. Is it possible that you also have a `library` stanza which does not list `gloss` in its `build-depends`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a separate `library` stanza in your package.yaml. You need to add the `gloss` dependency there.